# Is it Possible to redirect to installed flutter app page from react app when open in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flutter

is it possible to redirect to flutter installed mobile app from react-Js web app when web app open in mobile browser if it is possible than how?

i have read all plugins of flutter these allow to redirect from browser to web but actually i want to redirect from browser to flutter mobile app.

Comment: Are you looking for app/deep links? https://medium.com/flutter-community/deep-links-and-flutter-applications-how-to-handle-them-properly-8c9865af9283, using a URL to open the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to open the app, you can use the following (I am using the `instagram` app as example) -

## Android

```
const url =
        "intent://instagram.com/#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.instagram.android;end";

window.location.replace(url);
```

Replace the URL and the package name with your website's URL and the App's package name respectively.

## iOS

```
window.location.replace("instagram://");
```

Replace `instagram` with your app's name in App Store.